# Given a vertex in a digraph, is there a standard term for (the vertices reachable from it) union (the vertices reaching it)?

Tags: graphs, terminology, order-theory, directed-graphs

Question in title. Looking for whether there is a term that is, if not widely understood, at least citeable to a source.

This is equivalent to asking for the set of nodes that are comparable to the given node in the [preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) induced by the digraph. But that's as much of a mouthful as what I wrote in the title.

Example: Consider the following digraph.

[image: Digraphxample]

Given the above graph and the node `y`, I am looking for a term that refers to the set `{u, v, w, y, z}` but excludes `x`, because `x` is neither upstream nor downstream of `y`.

Comment: If understand correctly, you're looking for all vertices $a$ for which there exists a path from $y$ to $a$ (1) or a path from $a$ to $y$. Is that correct? Only (1) is called transitive closure, but you're probably aware of this.

Comment: @idmean That is correct.